# Rails aborted! ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, production

I am trying to to do a production migration and get the above error. In Dev mode they work fine but when I try to migrate to production I get this error.

```
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:24:in `initialize'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:60:in `new'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/cache.rb:60:in `lookup_store'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:67:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/home/Steven.Cahill/Brighter/Adviser/config/environment.rb:7:in `<main>'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/Steven.Cahill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
```

Comment: Please add more code for better debugging.

Comment: And check the guide for asking questions please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Check out Brighter/Adviser/config/environment.rb:7:in `'

This error indicates that rvm is having issues with requiring a few dependencies.

Check out your rvm setup

Comment: The trace is same as above but this only happens in Production. your command works in development

Answer (score 1):

You need specify correctly number of arguments when call this command